# Cpu, memory, network usage monitor for linux vps

Tags: linux, monitoring, vps

Is there a standalone monitoring software that reports cpu usage, memory usage and network traffic for a linux server?
I just switched vps providers and although much better the new one doesn't provide these stats like these http://www.elitehost.co.za/images/SolusVMstats.PNG

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@arthurprs there are so many monitoring tools which you can use

```
  1. Nagios
  2. Cacti 
  3. Munin
```